# User defined formulas, evaluation, and speed

Tags: c#

Lets say we have an array of a million elements, and we want to accept user input on what kind of math to apply to each of those elements.

Would the program need to evaluate the user formula (string) a million times, for each of the elements. Or can the formula itself somehow be saved and interpreted only once? And then be applied in a loop to the million elements?

I'm just trying to get a general idea on how this works. Because right now it looks like excel type programs are always interpreted which is way too slow for my data research. So basically what I'm doing is re-compiling my user defined math each and every time I change it. And there seems to be no way of compiling a program, and recompiling it while it itself is running. So that it could accept user input, compile it, and run it, without quitting. Maybe with DLLs and seperate app domains, but then all data has to be marshalled.

I just don't get how one gets top speed for data research, when everything is going against you. Including the stupid operating system that can't allow the DLL to be unloaded, loaded, because of security concerns. Or something. However maybe I'm just spurting nonsense, since I just began programming a few months ago.

Comment: There several formula parsers that can compile the formula. Afterwards you only have the overhead of a delegate call per evaluation, and it's otherwise as fast as normal C# code.

Comment: Hmm interesting I'll look into that, thanks! Right now I'm actually writing my formulas in Excel onto a sample data set. Then I have my program read excel, and automatically compile another program from the formulas in there. Perfectly imitating excel, but applying the formulas onto a lot more data. So I was wondering if one could have that whole solution in one program, instead of two where one compiles/writes, and the other one shows results, but always has to be turned off between runs. But you have maybe given me another solution, thanks!

Comment: If you need a custom parser, I'd have it output an `Expression<T>`, which .net 3.5 can compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are interested in, or prefer to implement the solution yourself, you could parse the formula into a (binary) tree, where each node represents an operator (+, -, *,..) or a function (cos(), max(),..) and each leaf represents either a constant or one of the formula's variables.

This can be done in a pretty efficient way and then applied to the entire data set by recursively calculating the value of the root while filling in the correct variables at the leaves.

To figure out how best to do this, this question might provide some pointers (though I am fairly certain the answer provided there is only one of several ways):
[Create Binary Tree from Mathematical Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381210/create-binary-tree-from-mathematical-expression)

Hope this helps or at least is of some interest to other readers!

Comment: Choosing as best answer because its interesting. However I've decided to keep using my current structure of auto-compiling another program based on data supplied to my code writing application. Later I'll figure out a way to combine those 2 programs into one, but for now I'll just make them share data, or use databases or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want user input against a data set and expressions compiled on the fly, then check out a suitable [C# REPL](http://rickardnilsson.net/post/2012/01/01/csharp-repl-and-interactive-interpreter.aspx).

You should be able to sumply type in your transformations etc., and have the REPL compile and apply them. It's a useful tool/technique for trying out solutions prior to coding them up properly in classes/components.