# How can I get numbers, operators and braces from regular expressions in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string[] num = Regex.Split(expr, @"\(|\)|\-|\+|\*|\/").Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

For this I am getting **operators** and **braces**.

Comment: `\d` http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: i tried \d it works if i use in new string array.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to take something like (4 + 4) and turn it into "(" "4" "+" "4" ")" in a string array?

Comment: ya something like tat. I am calculating an expression but stuck in providing precedence for expression if i take all numbers,operators and braces in single array then i can calculate eassily.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookaround i.e lookahead and lookbehind to split the input

```
 (?<=\(|\)|\-|\+|\*|\/)|(?=\(|\)|\-|\+|\*|\/)
                       ^
```

Without lookaround the regex engine would split on those characters and eat it i.e it won't show it in the result

If you want to evaluate mathematical expressions,have a look at these

- [Is there a string math evaluator in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net/392355#392355)
- [Create Binary Tree from Mathematical Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381210/create-binary-tree-from-mathematical-expression)

Comment: thank you but i dont want binary tree because i am trying something new. Cant i evaluate expression by using regular expression.

Comment: @user2499557 **NO**..you can't evaluate expression with regex only..i tried that once and failed to evaluate properly..after splitting the input,change it into postfix notation and evaluate using stack..check out the first link